# Windows 8 and Ubuntu on a dual-boot

Tags: discussion

This topic seems to crop up on a regular basis and to my untrained eyes, it seem that there is a floor in the installation software somewhere along the way.

- No install alongside Windows 8 option
- The Win 8 partitions do not seem to show if you try something else.

Is there a default page that we can recommend to users so that they get a full run down on the problems with Windows 8 and how to over come them?

I am presently sending them to the following question: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) which seems to give a fairly comprehensive, easy to follow answer.

These questions often get left, for quite a while, before they are answered, and then answered often with a different method, to resolve the issue, each time. This is confusing for the new user and can end up with them formatting their Windows 8 partition as well as their files.

Comment: I have also noticed this popular trend.

Comment: When you see this happening please flag the question so people can duplicate it.